# Get all the coordinates of a feature in OpenLayers 4

Tags: polygon, javascript, openlayers, geojson, coordinates

I am trying to highlight all the vertices (coordinates) of polygon by adding `ol.style.Style()` as in following code snippet.

```
var polygonStyles = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'orange'
        })
      }),
      geometry: function(feature) {
        // return the coordinates of the first ring of the polygon
        var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0]; //throws error if feature.getGeometry() returns an Object of GeometryCollection
        return new ol.geom.MultiPoint(coordinates);
      }
    })
```

But the problem is if the polygon Geometry is of type `GeometryCollection` then `var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0];` throws error (`ol.geom.GeometryCollection` does not have function `getCoordinates()` but again another `getGeometries()` function). 
Is there any method or any other workaround to get all the coordinates of the feature regardless of the type of Geometry returned from feature.getGeometry() function. The polygon is loaded into the vector as below.

```
var polygon = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                url: 'data.json'
            }),
            style: polygonStyles
        })
```

where `'data.json'` can have `geometry` of `type` either `MultiPolygon` or `GeometryCollection` as of now.

Answer (score 1):

Multipolygon has getCoordinates() method, but if you have GeometryCollection you should use somethink like this:

```
geometry: function(feature) {
    var geometries = feature.getGeometries();
    var coordinates = [];
    for (var key in geometries){
       //I use concat so I don't have array of arrays
       var coordinates.concat(geometries[key].getCoordinates());
    }
    return new ol.geom.MultiPoint(coordinates);
  }
```

Comment: What I was searching was a generic function that can be used for both Multipolygon and GeometryCollection. I solved the issue by checking the type of geometry
`var geom  = feature.getGeometry();
if(geom instanceof ol.geom.GeometryCollection){var geoms = geom.getGeometries();
                       for(let i = 0, len = geoms.length; i < len; i++){
                        getAllGeometries(geoms[i])
                       }
       } else if(geom instanceof ol.geom.SimpleGeometry){
        getAllCoordinates(geom.getCoordinates())
       }` Thanks for ur response @pszafer.